# Random string in lua

Tags: string, random, lua

I'm trying to create in a lua script a [function for generating random strings](https://gist.github.com/haggen/2fd643ea9a261fea2094).

This is my code:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
local charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
function string.random(length)
    if length > 0 then
        return string.random(length - 1) .. charset:sub(math.random(1, #charset), 1)
    else
        return ""
    end
end

-- Create the string
local scenarioname = string.random(10)
print ('the scenario name is ' .. scenarioname)
```

but the `scenarioname` string is always empty.

What I'm doing wrong? I'm using luajit

Comment: Second argument of `:sub` method is **not** the length of substring.

Comment: ESkri is spot on, that's the reason for your bug. I'd additionally like to point out that such repeated string concatenation results in poor (quadratic) runtime; you should either use a temporary table, or, if you only expect to generate "short" random strings which fit on the stack, you could generate a vararg of bytes and pass that to `string.char`.